# Is there a problem with Xamarin Forms project template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, templates, xamarin.forms

I followed the wizard to create a Xamarin.Form solution - and now I have

- App1
- App1.Android
- App1.iOS
- App1.Web

I have tested it and it works.

Then I have changed in the ItemRepository the items returned by the server; but the phone app (even after compile/restart) still shows the old values.

Could there be a caching problem on the server side?

Edit:
Of course it didn't worked!!! The data didn't come from the server, but it was generated locally to look like everything is ok.

I tried to link it to the server - of course it doesn't work; probably the template author couldn't do it either so that it generated the data locally.

Who would do such a thing? And it is the main Xamarin.Forms template of Visual Studio.

Comment: Xamarin can be flakey on the best of days. However its hard to know what your actual problem is, what you changed, how you are building and testing this.

Comment: Not enough information to find the cause of issue.. you need to check first if server returns your updated value in response.. if yes then you can check why its not updating in app side.

Comment: @Mukesh Modhvadiya I have checked in the browser; the data from the server is ok. I have edited the question as I found the problem.